# How to move UIView in superview

Tags: view, uiimageview, storyboard

I have a "main" view which controls by my UIViewController. I have added 2 labels and UIImageView to that view. Image in UIImageView is image of arrow and I want to move that image from one label to another.

I tried to set origin of UIViewImage from my controller, but Xcode show me error sign: "Expression is not assignable":

```
self.myArrowPointer.bounds.origin.y = 150.0;
```

I thought about making a View, that "wrap" that labels and this image view. And move this UIImageView from this view.m file through drawRect method. But I don't know how to do this if I made this objects (labels, UIImageView) from storyboard.

So, my question is how I can move UIImageView in my storyboard view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a setter, so you must pass whole structure. Like this:

```
CGRect bounds = self.myArrowPointer.bounds;
bounds.origin.y = 150;
self.myArrowPointer.bounds = bounds;
```

but you need to do this with `self.myArrowPointer.frame` or `self.myArrowPointer.center` to move image.

Comment: it works for origin.y but it doesn't work for origin.x, why? What could prevent that?

Comment: Try to use `self.myArrowPointer.frame` for this.